# Selection Sort with an ArrayList of objects

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, selection

I'm having some trouble with this sort. It will only display the first file correctly in order. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I've been trying to figure it out for hours now and just don't see what I'm doing wrong.

```
public void sort() { 

    int i; //loop control
    int last; //last position in the arraylist
    int max; //position where last alphabetical filename is found

    max = 0; //largest position so far is first, since i haven't checked

    //I thought i should start at the end and work my way down
    for(last = fileList.size()-1; last >= 0; last--) {

        for(i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
            if(fileList.get(max).getFileName().compareTo(fileList.get(i).getFileName()) > 0)
                max = i;
        }

        //swap pixfile in last position with the last alphabetical
        Pixfile tempPix = fileList.get(last);
        fileList.set(last, fileList.get(max));
        fileList.set(max, tempPix);
        //i thought i would repeat until last = 0 and the arraylist is sorted
    }//end for

}
```

Comment: Debugging exists to be used.

Comment: Please post some sample input and output.  Also describe the problem more.  Why are you implementing sort and not using `Collections.sort(fileList);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the inner for loop should be `for(int i = 0; i <= last; i++)` because you're selecting the best from what is still unsorted. everything after last you've sorted already in the previous iterations of the outer loop.

also, you're not resetting the value of `max` in each iteration, so before the inner for loop, write `max = 0;`

also, if you're too lazy to write a sorting algorithm, you can always use `Arrays.sort()` or `Collections.sort()`